# HTML: Background elements disappear when zooming out

Tags: css, html, background-image

In my website, the background elements disappear when I zoom out too much. It's a very simple site, but I used a template as I do not know much about html, so I don't actually know the code that well myself.

Here's a link: [juancallejas.com/SpaceBotKnights](http://www.juancallejas.com/SpaceBotKnights)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't actually hide. It's just the background color that changes.

The issue is in your CSS file. Find the line that says:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1680px) {
```

And replace it with something more appropriate, like:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1281px) {
```

Comment: That is it! Thank you very much for your help